# Some WP_Query parameters breaks while trying to fetch posts with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Something fails when I'm trying to fetch posts from a specific category using 'cat' parameter in WP_Query.

For example:

This works fine, but I want to fetch all posts from a specific category.

```
   $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'paged' => $_POST['paged'],
       'post_status' => 'publish'
   ));

   if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
```

But something fails when I'm adding 'cat' and the category id to my $args like this:

```
   $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'paged' => $_POST['paged'],
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'cat' => 3 // Category id I want to fetch posts from 
   ));

   if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
```

Does someone know why some parameters wont work?

Comment: What do you mean by it fails? Do you get an error? No posts? All posts? Some of the right posts?

Comment: @andrewsi It fetches no posts at all.

Comment: I apologise for having to ask, but you have checked that that category ID is the right one, haven't you?

Comment: Also, I think you can see the SQL you're generating with `echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request` - does the code it's generating look ok?

Comment: i can't see any ajax reference in your code

Comment: @andrewsi The category id is the right one, I have tried other ids (that contains posts) as well. I am creating a new WP_Query object and saving it to $my_query. So I'm using var_dump($my_query) to see the SQL I'm generating, and I think it looks ok.

Comment: @lassemt - is it just category 3 that's giving you this issue, or are you getting it for all of them? Could you paste the text of the query into your question? I'd also suggest trying a couple of the alternatives from the documentation - could you try using the category slug (rather than the ID), or try `'cat' => -2` to see what that retrieves?

Comment: @andrewsi I have the same issue on all the categories. Posts fetch normally if I add 'cat' => null, but then I'm not trying to fecth posts from a category. I have tried using the slug and category__in as well. I think this could be the solution: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82092/wp-query-orderby-breaks-when-using-ajax I will try this out tomorrow, Ill give you a headsup if its workign or not! Thank you for your help :) Gnight from Norway!

Comment: This worked for me: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82242